# Difference in rendering of negative text indent layout between Chrome & Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I use padding and a negative text-indent to create an indented layout for responsive forms but now want to make the bottom paragraph a block level element so it always wraps.

The layout works fine when the bottom row is display inline or inline-block but as soon as the bottom row is display block then the entire layout in Chrome changes.

I don't know which browser is right, but it is Firefox's interpretation of the layout that I am after.

This is a simplified version of a layout I use for forms to attempt to fix this problem.

http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/rxxxRj

```
<div>
  <div>
    <p class="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p class="bottom">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    div div {padding-left: 36%; margin: 0; text-indent: -18%; background-color: #cee; width: 300px;}
    p {text-indent: 0;}
    p.top {display: inline-block; background-color: #ffc;}
    p.bottom {display: block; width: 200px; background-color: #fcf;}
</style>
```

[image: Example of layouts]
[image: This is the a screenshot of the code being used in the wild.]

Real world example of how this code is being used.

Comment: I have made some progress by making the container display inline. http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/yeeJqG?editors=110 this works until I add a width to the p elements which is unfortunately necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by changing from using padding to margin on the parent container and then adjusting the sizes after that.